# How do I group SQLITE records by date, allowing for the timezone?

Tags: php, sqlite, timezone

I am using SQLITE within PHP to produce a summary of records by date, from a database that contains Unix times as numbers, but it doesn't seem to be splitting the records correctly for the timezone.

I first set the PHP time zone to GMT+8:

```
date_default_timezone_set ("Asia/Makassar");
```

Then I do this SQLITE query:

```
SELECT DATE([datetime],'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS [date], COUNT (*) AS [number],  SUM([duration]) AS [ds], MAX ([peak]) AS [pm], SUM ([total]) AS [ts] from $table WHERE datetime >= $period_start and datetime <= $period_end GROUP BY [date]
```

There are no records for 2021-07-02, and there are 11 records for 2021-07-03. Here they are:

```
Time        duration total  peak
04:23:33    9:14    0.34    6.2
04:36:07    4:30    0.14    14.1
05:14:17    7:39    0.4     13.9
05:24:26    16:40   2.34    26.9
05:41:35    5:59    0.43    43.7
05:49:48    6:34    0.13    8
06:03:16    16:22   3.09    61.6
06:31:21    3:15    0.03    9
06:40:25    12:15   1.98    51.8
06:56:46    4:24    0.09    11.2
13:03:01    3:27    0.04    14.6
```

... and this is the summary I get from the SQLITE query:

```
Date        No  Dur     Total   Peak
2021-07-01  2   7:21    0.08    19
2021-07-02  6   50:36   3.78    44
2021-07-03  5   39:43   5.23    62
```

As you can see, the first six records on 21-07-03 (those before 6am local time) have been moved back to the previous day. This behaviour occurs consistently for days that have records before 6am.

Comment: What happens if you remove `'localtime'` from `DATE()`?

Comment: @forpas without localtime, the situation is worse: the summary shows 10 records for 2021-07-02.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the timestamps by adding 6 hours:

```
DATE([datetime], 'unixepoch', 'localtime', '+6 hour')
```

Comment: ... any idea why I need to add anything at all, and why particularly six hours, given that the timezone offset is 8 hours? Will that correction be valid for other timezones? The times on the detail report are printed out from the SQL table using the PHP function "date ('H:i:s', (int) $row['datetime'])", and they are correct.

Comment: @JavaLatte The result returned by SQLite functions like date() or datetime() are not affected by your PHP settings. Their results are based on the system settings where the query is ran. About the 6 hours: I proposed that because you mention in your question: *This behaviour occurs consistently for days that have records before 6am* I don't have your actual data and since your timestamps are unix epochs I only know form the issue that you described that they need adjustment.

Comment: you are right: there is no way to set the timezone that SQLITE uses. My server's timezone is CEST, and there is no way to change SQLITE's opinion on the matter if the data is from a different timezone. The people who Know About These Things say that you should do your timezone manipulation in the  application language (in this case, PHP) rather than in SQL. In my case, that means doing a separate query for every. single. day.

Comment: Adding a fixed offset doesn't work, even for one particular timezone: WITA is always +0800, but CEST is +0200 and CET is +0100, and you don't know from outside the SQL query whether the date in a particular record is going to be CEST or CET.

Comment: @JavaLatte you store the timestamps as unix time which is an absolute timing system. You should know what these values represent. I only proposed the +6 hour adjustment because this is what you mention in your question.

Comment: The six-hour time difference is not the problem, but a symptom of the problem. The real problem is that SQLITE ignores the timezone set by PHP. Because of this, an SQL query cannot be used to correctly GROUP records into days in a timezone other than localtime, because SQLITE has to decide on a per-record basis whether to apply daylight saving time, and so simply adding a fixed offset to the query will not work.

Comment: @JavaLatte SQLite does not know anything about the PHP settings. It lies one level below your PHP code which gets the SQLite's results.

Comment: Exactly. SQLITE does not provide any way to use any timezone other than the system timezone, and without that it is impossible to reliably group records by date, unless they are in the system timezone.

Comment: @JavaLatte that's right and it is all explained here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html